# Error: "Left of getValue must have class/struct/union"

Tags: c++

In addition to the error in the title, it says that `A2` and `A1` are undeclared identifiers and that `Result::calResult:function` does not take 2 arguments, but it does in its implementation. And lastly, it says that left of `getValue` must have class/struct/union.

I am new to C++ and am trying to create a program that compares 3 elements of two arrays, I know this is not the best way to do this but I am trying to get my head around objects and classes.

**Main.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "ArrayOfThree.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ArrayOfThree A1, A2;
    Result R;
    int i = 0;
    int input;
    for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {   
        cin >> input;
        A1.set(i, input);

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cin >> input;
        A2.set(i, input);
    }
    R.CalResult(A1, A2);
    R.outResult();

    return 0;
}
```

**ArrayOfThree.h**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Result.h"
using namespace std;

class ArrayOfThree {
private:
    int a1, a2, a3;
public:
    ArrayOfThree() {
        a1 = 0; a2 = 0; a3 = 0;
    }

    void set(int index,int input) { 
        if (index == 0)
            a1 = input;
        else if (index == 1)
            a2 = input;
        else if (index == 2)
            a3 = input;
        else
            cout << "Index out of bound" << endl;
    }
    int getValue(int index) {
        if (index == 0)
            return a1;
        else if (index == 1)
            return a2;
        else if (index == 2)
            return a3;
        else
            cout << "Index out of bound" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
};
```

**Result.h**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Result {

private:
    int r1=0, r2=0;
    char R;

public:
    Result() { r1 = 0; r2 = 0; R = ' '; }

    void CalResult(ArrayOfThree A1, ArrayOfThree A2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            if (A1.getValue(i) < A2.getValue(i))
                r2++;
            else if (A1.getValue(i) > A2.getValue(i))
                r1++;
            else
                r1 = r1;
        }
        if (r1 < r2)
            R = 'B';
        else if (r1 > r2)
            R = 'A';
        else
            R = 'T';
    }

    void outResult()
    {
        if (R == 'B' || R == 'A')
            cout << "The winner is :" << R;
        else
            cout << "Its a Tie" << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: You code suffers from circular dependency. Hope this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes

Comment: Ask yourself does AOT really need to include Result? Does result really need to include AOT?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, your `#includes` are a bit messed up.

In your `ArrayOfThree.h` header, you're including `Result.h` even though you're not using any code from `Result.h` in your `ArrayOfThree.h` header.

On the other hand, the `Result.h` header is using the `ArrayOfThree` class which is defined in the `ArrayOfThree.h` header, but the `Result.h` doesn't include this header.

You have to include the header files of all classes, functions, etc that you're using.
So to fix your problem, add `#include "ArrayOfThree.h"` into your `Result.h` header and remove the `#include "Result.h"` from your `ArrayOfThree.h` header.

---

Even better way to structure your code would be to split declaration and definition of your classes. That means you'd have a TU (*Translation Unit*) for your `ArrayOfThree`, as well as for `Result` classes.

For example, your `Result.h` file would become:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ArrayOfThree.h"

class Result {
private:
    int r1=0, r2=0;
    char R;

public:
    Result();

    void CalResult(ArrayOfThree A1, ArrayOfThree A2);

    void outResult();
};
```

And you'd have a new *TU* in your project `Result.cpp` which would look like this:

```
#include "Result.h" // In the implementation file, you need to include the
                    // declaration of the class that you're implementing here.
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Result::Result() { r1 = 0; r2 = 0; R = ' '; }

void Result::CalResult(ArrayOfThree A1, ArrayOfThree A2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if (A1.getValue(i) < A2.getValue(i))
            r2++;
        else if (A1.getValue(i) > A2.getValue(i))
            r1++;
        else
            r1 = r1;
    }
    if (r1 < r2)
        R = 'B';
    else if (r1 > r2)
        R = 'A';
    else
        R = 'T';
}

void Result::outResult()
{
    if (R == 'B' || R == 'A')
        cout << "The winner is :" << R;
    else
        cout << "Its a Tie" << endl;
}
```

Note that now, your `Result.h` header doesn't `#include <iostream>`. That's because the `Result.h` header doesn't depend on anything from `iostream` because the parts that were depending on `iostream` were moved to the implementation file `Result.cpp`, which includes the `iostream` header.